# I accidentally changed the gnome panel background color, how can I change it back?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

So I accidentally dragged an image onto the top bar and it changed the background to that image. I looked into the Appearance settings, changed themes, and the image is still there. Is there anyway to reset it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this in the Compiz based gnome-flashback, but you can change it in flashback-no-effects and it will take effect in the regular gnome-flashback too.

Log out and log into gnome-flashback-no-effects.  Then <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Right Click</kbd>  the panel and click "Properties".

[image]

Switch to the "Background" tab and select "None (use system theme)".

[image]

Then log out and log back into the regular gnome-flashback.

Comment: Thanks! I just need to hold down Alt to bring up the right click menu.